# Manual Installation of Glassfish on Ubuntu

Tags: glassfish, environment-variables, ubuntu-9.04

I just installed Glassfish on my **Ubuntu** server (No GUI) using [THIS](http://computingwithjasper.blogspot.com/2008/01/installing-glassfish-2-on-ubuntu-710.html) tutorial. Everything went well. But now when I'm trying to play with ASADMIN tool it's telling me this:

> The program 'asadmin' is currently not
>   installed.  You can install it by
>   typing: apt-get install glassfishv2
>   -bash: asadmin: command not found

So, in order to run asadmin tool always need to type:

> /opt/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1

or go to that folder and run it from there.

So, the question is, what file do i need to edit in order to set this path in to the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your ~/.bashrc file to add all the binaries in /opt/glassfish/bin to your $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/glassfish/bin
```

~ expands to /home/your-user - just to be clear.

Comment: Yeah.. that was easy, I tough I need to do some "magic" trick to disable ubuntu's feature. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just type to CLI:

> export PATH=/opt/glassfish/bin/:$PATH